# Changing Harddisks and recovery media

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad whose hard disk has started giving errors (but still works). Lenovo is replacing the HD under the 3 year warranty. However, they say the OS and data is my baby, they have nothing to do with that. I never got a OS installation media with the Laptop either originally. They had the HDD Partioned and a Q Driver created with a recovery media but once the HDD is replaced, I won't be able to use it.

So I went to the Lenovo Solution Center and created a USB Bootable Recovery Disk (on my 32 GB Sandisk Pen Driver). The Solution Center formatted my drive, named it cbd_drive & filled up around 12 GB on the driver.

I tried to boot with this but it doesn't boot - it boots through my regular HD (my HD is still not exchanged).

In BIOS boot priority order, I have USB Sandisk as first option and USB CD as 2nd.

How do I check if this USB recovery media I created will actually work once the drive is replaced.

This is a listing of the USB drive

```
F:\>dir /a
 Volume in drive F is cbd_drive
 Volume Serial Number is 3263-7841

 Directory of F:\

13-03-2015  10:56    <DIR>          $RECYCLE.BIN
15-12-2011  08:35                49 AUTORUN.INF
11-03-2015  01:23    <DIR>          Boot
21-11-2010  08:53           383,786 bootmgr
11-03-2015  01:57    <DIR>          factoryrecovery
15-12-2011  08:35           267,576 LenovoQDrive.exe
15-12-2011  08:35           422,982 qdrive.ico
13-03-2015  10:55    <DIR>          System Volume Information
11-03-2015  01:58                15 usb.tag
11-03-2015  01:08       330,879,497 winRE.wim
               6 File(s)    331,953,905 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  19,221,176,320 bytes free
```

Comment: Did the computer come preinstalled with Windows 7? Is the COA sticker on the side? If yes then I'm sure if the hard disk has failed/failing under warranty then they should fix/replace and reinstall the OS using a factory image. It's under warranty and you bought it with an OS. A warranty repair should, at least, get the computer back to how it left the factory in the first place. I've never experienced this from any manufacturer. Most of the time they put a clean Windows on and if you haven't backed up then tough luck!

Comment: Having said that, with your BIOS, do you UEFI/secure boot enabled? This may be preventing the board from booting from the USB.

Comment: @BigChris   No. Lenovo says OS is my baby - checked again with them. Let me check the BIOS options.

Comment: @BigChris - Changing from UEFI to Legacy Boot didn't help. My OS isn't booting through the USB.

Comment: Is the USB set to be bootable? Not through the BIOS, the device/partition has to be bootable/active...